# Two questions about uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$ are functions, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets of real numbers. If $f$ is uniformly continuous and $g$ is pointwise continuous, is $f\circ g$ uniformly continuous? If $f$ is pointwise continuous and $g$ is uniformly continuous, is $f \circ g$ uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the answers are **no**.

1. Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be defined by $g(x)=x^2$. Clearly $f$ is uniformly continuous and $g$ is continuous, but $(f\circ g)(x)=\sin x^2$ is not uniformly continuous as you can easily verify.
2. Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2$ and $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be defined by $g(x)=x$. Clearly $f$ is  continuous and $g$ is uniformly continuous, but $(f\circ g)(x)= x^2$ is not uniformly continuous.